# How to make a continuous fill in a ggplot2 bar plot with one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the library `ggplot2movies` for my data `movies`

Please keep in mind that I refer to mpaa rating and user rating, which are two different things. In case you don't want to load the `ggplot2movies` library, here is a sample of the relevant data:

```
> head(subset(movies[,c(5,17)], movies$mpaa!=""))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  rating mpaa 
   <dbl> <chr>
1    5.3 R    
2    7.1 PG-13
3    7.2 PG-13
4    4.9 R    
5    4.8 PG-13
6    6.7 PG-13
```

Here I make a barplot that shows the frequency of films that have any mpaa rating:

```
ggplot(data=subset(movies, movies$mpaa!=""), aes(mpaa)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Now I would like to color in the bars with a fill, based on the imdb user rating. I don't want to use `factor(rating)` because there are an enormous number of different values in the rating column. However, when I try to use a continuous fill like in [Assigning continuous fill color to geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181730/assigning-continuous-fill-color-to-geom-bar) I get the same graph.

```
ggplot(data=subset(movies, movies$mpaa!=""), aes(mpaa, fill=rating)) +
  geom_bar()+ 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red")
```

I figure it has to do with the fact that my barplot is based on the frequency of a single variable, rather than a dataframe with a count column. I could make a new dataframe of the mpaa categories and their counts, but I'd rather know how to do this graph with the original `movies` dataset and a single ggplot.

Edit: Using `aes(mpaa, group = rating, fill = rating)` gives a chart that is almost correct, except that the bars and legend are swapped.
[image]

Comment: I mean I don't want to use factors, I want a continuous scale. So each bar will be a gradient from blue to red, with red being higher user rating. I guess I could cut into discrete groups, but again that would give a discrete fill, not continuous.

Comment: You can try `aes(mpaa, group = rating, fill = rating)`

Comment: This might be working, or might not. The bars are now gradients, but the bars and the scale are swapped. https://i.imgur.com/0qlXOQq.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the legend with: `+ guides(fill=guide_colourbar(reverse=TRUE))`, however, a colour gradient doesn't seem very informative. Another option would be to cut `rating` into discrete ranges, as in the example below, which provides a more clear indication of the distribution of ratings within each `mpaa` category. Nevertheless, because of the different bar heights, it's not clear how the average rating or distribution of ratings varies by `mpaa` category.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2movies)
theme_set(theme_classic())

movies %>% 
  filter(mpaa != "") %>% 
  mutate(rating = fct_rev(cut(rating, seq(0,ceiling(max(rating)),2)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpaa, fill=rating)) +
    geom_bar(colour="white", size=0.2) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c(hcl(240,100,c(30,70)), "yellow", hcl(0,100,c(70,30))))
```

[image]

Perhaps a boxplot or violin plot would be more informative. In the boxplot example below, the box widths are proportional to the square root of the number of movies rated, due to the `varwidth=TRUE` argument (I'm not that wild about this because the square-root transformation is difficult to interpret, but I thought I'd put it out there as an option). In the violin plot, the area of each violin is proportional to the number of movies in each `mpaa` category (due to the `scale="count"` argument). I've also put the number of movies in each category in the x-axis label, and marked in blue the mean rating for each `mpaa` category.

```
p = movies %>% 
  filter(mpaa != "") %>% 
  group_by(mpaa) %>% 
  mutate(xlab = paste0(mpaa, "\n(", format(n(), big.mark=","), ")")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xlab, rating)) +
    labs(x="MPAA Rating\n(number of movies)", 
         y="Viewer Rating") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10))

pl = list(geom_boxplot(varwidth=TRUE, colour="grey70"),
          geom_violin(colour="grey70", scale="count",
                      draw_quantiles=c(0.25,0.5,0.75)),
          stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)), 
                         colour="blue", size=3.5))  

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p + pl[-2], p + pl[-1], ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I agree and would go so far as to suggest the gradient adds no informational value whatsoever.

Comment: It's true that the gradient doesn't offer much informational value. However, if the groups had similar sizes and the rating distribution was more varied, the continuous fill could offer some interesting results. I'm still learning R, so knowing how to do this is helpful, whether it ended up being a useful visualization or not. Also, this answer gave some more useful alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the following is what you want.
When coloring by `rating` the default `stat = "count"` is not working so I transform the data.

```
library(ggplot2movies)
library(dplyr)

data("movies")

subset(movies, mpaa != "") %>%
  group_by(mpaa) %>%
  summarise(rating = sum(rating)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpaa, y = rating, fill = rating)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: No, if you sum the rating then of course the category with more values will have a higher end value. Using the mean of rating would give the answer you were looking for, but https://i.imgur.com/0qlXOQq.png is more what I am thinking about. However, in this example the bars and legend are swapped so I'm not sure it's correct.